# GET request to mp3 in S3 bucket failing to download file with 206 partial content?

Tags: ajax, amazon-s3

I have an mp3 file in an S3 bucket. I am fetching this file via ajax GET request for html5 audio playback. Intermittently, the get request will fail to download the file and thus the track will not play. The request returns "206 partial content." Oddly, it will work several times before failing and then continuing to fail.

If I disable caching in my browser (chrome), the file will download and play appropriately.

Have I configured s3 incorrectly? How can I get this mp3 file to download and play consistently?

specific file is located here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/1m40s_dev/assets/music/walden.mp3

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by appending a timestamp to the end of the mp3 url on page load. This forced a new download of the content each time and eliminated the caching error.

This feels more like a work around than a fix. I still don't know the root cause of the issue but if you find yourself having a similar problem and just need to move on, add a timestamp or random number as a param at the end of the url

```
.../assets/music/walden.mp3?[timestamp]
```

Comment: i'm having the same problem with some PNGs, although it is failing always with "206 - partial content". did you ever find out what the cause was?

Answer (score 2):

I've found this often relates to the MIME type set on the S3 hosted file.
Setting the correct MIME type seems to fix things.

On a side note, I struggled with a single binary file always breaking in IE. Its MIME type was application/octet-stream. I changed the MIME to binary/octet-stream and that seemed to fix downloads from IE. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

use amazon cloudfront solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

One other workaround I've found is, if you're using rails, turning off turbolinks makes this go away on chrome. I'll add more to my answer as I discover more.